# Is there a way to install the vscode plugin offline in the local WSL via vscode's ssh?

Tags: cmake, windows-subsystem-for-linux, offline, clangd, vscode-plugin

IDE: Vscode 1.87.2
OS: Windows10 + WSL(Ubuntu22.04)

My Story:
I learned in an article that you can connect to remote Linux through the VSCode SSH plugin, and remotely install CLANGD, CMAKE, CMAKE Tools and other plug-in tools through VSCode SSH, so as to make it easier to compile and package remotely.

In order to make it easier to verify and learn, I installed WSL locally on Windows 10 and successfully connected to the WSL located in localhost through VSCode through the installation vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz.

But when I try to install the clangd, cmake, cmake tools plugins for wsl that are already installed in my local vscode using ssh, I get 'XHR Failed' again.

IDE: Vscode 1.87.2
OS: Windows10 + WSL(Ubuntu22.04)

My Story:
I learned in an article that you can connect to remote Linux through the VSCode SSH plugin, and remotely install CLANGD, CMAKE, CMAKE Tools and other plug-in tools through VSCode SSH, so as to make it easier to compile and package remotely.

In order to make it easier to verify and learn, I installed WSL locally on Windows 10 and successfully connected to the WSL located in localhost through VSCode through the installation vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz.

But when I try to install the clangd, cmake, cmake tools plugins for wsl that are already installed in my local vscode using ssh, I get 'XHR Failed' again.

I think I might need to .tar.gz the corresponding plugin package, similar to the vscode-server-linux-x64.tar.gz, by installing the package into the WSL environment to unzip the installation.

To solve this problem, I tried searching Baidu (Chinese search engine), GitHub but nothing came of it.

If you really have no choice, you can only use the plugin and use some shell command line instead, but after all, I feel more troublesome, and it is not as beautiful and easy to use as the plugin GUI provided by VSCODE.

So I would like to ask you how to solve this problem?